# How do I add xml in HTML 5 document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Is it possible to add xml data in a html document?

like

```
<xml>
 <fruits>
  <apple color="red" />
  <peach color="link" />
 </fruits>
</xml>
```

and access it with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why do you want to add the xml data in the HTML page.

If you just want to display it, you can simply put it in the textarea. If you want to manipulate the data of xml, you can translate it to a javascript array or a json object, such as:

```
var fruits = {
    apple: red,
    peach: link
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You miight find this helpful:

http://norman.walsh.name/2011/03/26/HTML-XML-Prague

The basic answer is that the best you can probably do is to put your XML in a script element - but that won't make it accessible via the HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

not to be blunt, but did you try it?

And yes, it is possible, and no it will not be html5 valid

`console.log($('apple').attr('color'));`

will output 'red'